# How to dynamically create a JSON file for each Object that gets added to another JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, sails.js

I would like to dynamically create a corresponding JSON file every time a new merchant signs up to my site.

For example:

Burger King signs up to be a merchant on my site. I add Burger king to my merchants.json file. How would I dynamically create a file that gets inserted into that JSON object that can later be used to pull up data specific to that merchant, on that merchants page. For example, a JSON file full of products or deals.

Is this even the right way to go about it?

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

This seems like a very common usage scenario but I don't see any examples online that explain this application structure thoroughly.

NOTE: I am using AngularJS

**EDIT:** Thanks for the tips guys, after asking around in the #AngularJS channel on IRC, I've been told to go the extra mile and create an API. I'll probably use sails.js to help with that. This obviously isn't how I was planning to do things, but as you guys pointed out, it wasn't the best practice; not by a long shot.

Comment: You need to have a serverside component (whether Node.js, or PHP, any other serverside web service). You also might want to consider a database instead of JSON files.

Answer (score 0):

1) You'd need a small server-side PHP script that accepts the new JSON file sent by the client

2) Browser requests merchants.json from the server

3) Load it with JSON.parse()

4) Add the merchant to the Object

4) JSON.stringify(object)

5) Send back to the server.

Now, this is a horrible horrible idea. Use a server-side database for storing any kind of information on your clients -- MySQL, whatever. JSON is for **transporting** data, not storing it. You can write some PHP scripts to dynamically generate a page for your merchant based on the data in the database -- so much easier and so much more secure. The method above will expose the whole client database to the client, and based on your specifications above, I don't see another way.

Comment: Then again, this sounds kinda like MongoDB. It's basically JSONs used as a database

Comment: Yeah but Mango actually works with queries, so you'd use them to add/get data. You are not actually manipulating JSON files directly -- still a database system. What the OP wants looks like a file-based database with JSON formatting: no benefits of using a database API and all the downsides of file-based data storage.